# Cmake SFML font not loading

Tags: c++, cmake, sfml

So I've made a simple project with c++ and SFML.
I've wanted to compile it and build with cmake so that I can open it like an actual app.
I can compile and build it but then when I try to open that unix file it gives me an error "Failed to load font". When I run the same code in the Clion it works fine. I am using macOS Sonoma 14.1.1 .

Cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.27)
project(space_shooter_game)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)


set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(space_shooter_game ${SOURCE_FILES})
include_directories(/usr/local/include)

find_package(SFML 2.5 COMPONENTS system window graphics network audio REQUIRED)
include_directories(${SFML_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(space_shooter_game sfml-system sfml-window sfml-graphics sfml-audio sfml-network)
```

Part of code

```
if (!font.loadFromFile("font.ttf")) { 
        std::cerr << "Cannot load font" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I want to somehow link the file so that I can use relative path to the font.
I've tried to use absolute path and it works fine that way so I guess it's somehow that I need to link that font file to be able to use relative path.

Comment: Are you aware of the current working directory vs. the executable path?

Comment: What I usually do is a) find the path of the currently running executable on the current platform. b) use a path relative to the path of my executable to load the font from a known location relative to it (I know what my installer installs where). So for example, if my application is running as `/opt/myapp/bin/myapplication` then I know my font will be in `/opt/myapp/resources/font.ttf` since that's where my installer puts it. So I strip off the application name (`myapplication`) from the first path and add `../resources/font.ttf` to get `/opt/myapp/bin/../resources/font.ttf` - works nicely.